# Localhost to domain name

Tags: xampp, localhost, domain-name

Maybe it's a stupid question, but anyways:
How can I change 127.0.0.1 (localhost) to a domain name (www.example.com) for users to access worldwide? Is that possible?
If it matters - I'm using XAMPP v1.8.3
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To connect to your computer someone needs your IP. So first you must have a static IP (contact your internet provider for this) or at least use a service like [this](http://www.noip.com/).

A domain name is a whole different process. As soon as you have your static IP try to experiment with a free domain service like [this one here](http://www.dot.tk/en/index.html?lang=en).

You should find instructions on the second site.

And one friendly advice: Please try to form your questions better. Do a little research by yourself and then ask a specific question **IF** you don't find the answer yourself.
The question you asked is too general. Its like asking "Hey, how can I build a house?".

The answer you require on questions like that cannot be formed in a single forum response.

Best Regards.